# Laravel Homestead: requested URL could not be retrieved (working behind proxy)

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, homestead

I'm working on a Windows 10 notebook behind a corporate proxy. Finally I've managed to set up VirtualBox, Vagrant and Homestead.

Unfortunately I'm not able to access my sites in the browser. It says: the requested URL could not be retrieved, unable to determine IP address from host name "test.app".

I've installed the vagrant plugin [vagrant-proxyconf](https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-proxyconf) and set it up in my Vagrantfile within my Homestead-folder. I've added the following lines to my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION ||= "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = confDir + "/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.require_version '>= 1.9.0'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

    if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-proxyconf")
        config.proxy.http     = "http://proxy.my.proxy.com:3128"
        config.proxy.https    = "http://proxy.my.proxy.com:3128"
        config.proxy.no_proxy = "localhost,127.0.0.1,192.168.10.10"
    end
    # ... default configuration
end
```

This is my Homestead.yaml:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:/Users/wn00111510/Projekte/ContentAnalyzer
      to: /home/vagrant/contentanalyzer
    - map: C:/Users/wn00111510/Projekte/Test
      to: /home/vagrant/test

sites:
    - map: test.app
      to: /home/vagrant/test

databases:
    - homestead
```

My hosts-file has only one entry:

```
192.168.10.10    test.app
```

The machine is running and I'm able to login into my virtual machine via vagrant ssh. vagrant reload --provision does not change something.

During booting there is a warning about a connection reset:

```
...
Booting VM...
Waiting for machine to boot. THis may take a few minutes...
SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
SSH username: vagrant
SSH auth method: private key
Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
Warning: Remote Connection disconnect. Retrying...
Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
Warning: Remote Connection disconnect. Retrying...
Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
Machine booted and ready!
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on proxies, but since this is local to your machine you *should* be able to just bypass any proxy. Have you tried without the proxy plugin?.

The errors here:

```
Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
Warning: Remote Connection disconnect. Retrying...
```

Are usually no big deal as long as the machine connects in a reasonable time.

Since you're only mapping 1 site to the machine, you should also be able to bypass DNS completely by using http://localhost:8000 (or different port that Vagrant mapped to 80 during the `vagrant up` process).